# How to convert text to speech in python 3.5 on windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, text-to-speech

I tried espeak but didn't succeed and some functionalities only supported in python 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using Google Text-to-Speech via [gTTS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gTTS)?

The syntax for using it in Python 3.x is as follows:

```
from gtts import gTTS
my_tts = "Text you want to process"
tts = gTTS(text=my_tts, lang='en')
tts.save("Absolute/path/to/file.mp3")
```

Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS) of gTTS.

Comment: If I use gTTS my application would have to run online,right?I want some offline solution of text to speech.

Comment: gTTS sadly is online. I'll look for offline solutions but till then gTTS is your best bet. Also @kingforever your question didn't specify the requirement for it to work offline. And using TTS offline would frankly be a bad choice as you'd have to have tons of data (for each word) for working of TTS. So why not leave it on Google'e behalf? Plus for each language you choose to implement you'd have yet more data. It simply won't be worth the time or effort.

Comment: I am making talking calculator in tkinter GUI and I am very new to GUI. If there are not any other option I better try gTTS.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kingforever : Accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark below the voting button as it has solved your problem so that  others facing this problem would then know the solution.

Answer (score 16):

For offline use in Windows, use SAPI directly.

You can use [SpVoice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723602(v=vs.85)).

```
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("Jumpman Jumpman Jumpman Them boys up to something!")
```

Comment: `pip install pywin32` if `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'`.